# C# Convert a int method into a string method

Tags: c#, string, methods, fusioncharts, axes

I'm working with Fusionchart and I need to label the axes.
It's working with int but I need a string for the axes

```
 public int GetyAxisName(int chartId)
{
    Chart_AttributeModel chart_AttributeModel = new Chart_AttributeModel();
    List<Chart_Attribute> attributes = chart_AttributeModel.GetChart_AttributeByChart(chartId);

    AttributeModel attributeModel = new AttributeModel();

    int yAxisName = new int();
    foreach (Chart_Attribute ca in attributes)
    {
        Attribute a = attributeModel.GetAttribute(ca.AID);
        if (a.Name == "yAxisName")
        {
            yAxisName = Convert.ToInt32(ca.Value);
        }
    }

    return yAxisName;
}
```

But if I want to change it to string it doesn't work.
What's wrong with the code?

```
 public string GetyAxisName(int chartId)
{
    Chart_AttributeModel chart_AttributeModel = new Chart_AttributeModel();
    List<Chart_Attribute> attributes = chart_AttributeModel.GetChart_AttributeByChart(chartId);

    AttributeModel attributeModel = new AttributeModel();

    string yAxisName = new string();
    foreach (Chart_Attribute ca in attributes)
    {
        Attribute a = attributeModel.GetAttribute(ca.AID);
        if (a.Name == "yAxisName")
        {
            yAxisName = Convert.ToString(ca.Value);
        }
    }

    return yAxisName;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What type is ca.Value?  Did you try ca.Value.ToString()?

Comment: A bit more information would be useful, what do you mean by 'it doesnt work'?

Comment: Show us `Chart_Attribute`. It will help alot.

Comment: Do you get an error, an empty value, a null, something else? It's impossible to guess what's going on when you don't mention the actual problem or significant information like what `Value` is and what it contains

Comment: So I've got a database with the table Chart_Attribute where you can type the value of the xAxis in and then it should take this as a string for the XAxis .The value could be something like week or month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only visible error is `string yAxisName1 = new string();`

String does not contain constructor with 0 arguments. so make it `string yAxisName1 = "";`

Comment: Thanks, it worked like that. But can you explain what this constructer means?

Comment: see here:https://www.google.co.in/#q=what+is+a+constructor        A constructor is a bit of code that allows you to create objects from a class. You call the constructor by using the keyword new , followed by the name of the class, followed by any necessary parameters. For example, if you have a Dog class, you can create new objects of this type by saying new Dog()